# Kendo UI vs DevExpress for Angular4

Tags: kendo-ui, devexpress, kendo-ui-angular2, devextreme

We are going to start a new project in Angular4. Now we are analysing some third part libraries. There are two candidates

1) Kendo UI
2) Devexpress

Discussing with others developers it looks like Kendo is more popular than Devexpress, but controls and component of DevExpress are more powerful.

I need to decide based on Features, Performance, complexity and support.

Answer (score 0):

We have selected DevExtreme tools for Angular4 and it's going pretty good. Devextreme have lot of components which will fulfill most of the project needs and coming to performance it's good and I don't see any drawback on that.

Support is good, you may not get the solution within an hour but within 24 hours you will get response from DevExtreme team, It would be good if they have voice support which is not there currently.

Documentation, It's Good.